# How to handle null values from SQLite DB with C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
EDIT:
Thanks to everyone who replied! I appreciate all of your answers :)
```

So I have a class with the following constructor:

```
public Transaction(DataRow row)
    {
        LastName = row.Field<string>("LastName");
        FirstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName");
        MI = row.ItemArray[3].ToString()[0];
        ContactNumber = row.ItemArray[4].ToString();
        Hours = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[5].ToString());
        CheckIn = (DateTime)row.ItemArray[6];
        roomNumber = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[9].ToString());
        //Paid = row.Field<int>("Paid");
        //TotalBill = row.Field<int>("TotalBill");
    }
```

Notice I have 2 of them commented out with /'s That's because if I don't they return null values even if I try ''row.Field([Whatever]).GetValueOrDefault()'', it still comes out null and my constructor returns null. I also have my DB set with default values so IDK what's wrong.
Anyone got a work around? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataRow class has a method that is called [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx)  and that could receive the column name.
Just combine it with the conditional operator

```
  Paid = row.IsNull("Paid") ? 0 : row.Field<int>("Paid");
```

the same is true for all other fields that could  contain a null value.

Comment: Thanks! I found your answer to be the most elegant one :)

Answer (score 2):

Just check for `null` first and supply a default value:

```
public Transaction(DataRow row)
{
    LastName = row.Field<string>("LastName");
    FirstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName");
    MI = row.ItemArray[3].ToString()[0];
    ContactNumber = row.ItemArray[4].ToString();
    Hours = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[5].ToString());
    CheckIn = (DateTime)row.ItemArray[6];
    roomNumber = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[9].ToString());
    Paid = row.Field<int?>("Paid") ?? 0;
    TotalBill = row.Field<int?>("TotalBill") ?? 0;
}
```

See the [?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) page on MSDN for further information on the `??` operator.

Comment: That won't compile int can't be null.

Comment: Field<> supports nullable types. You can use `Field<int?>("Paid") ??0`

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos... I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Nullable type and `GetValueOrDefault` method or use null coalescing operator.

```
Paid = row.Field<int?>("Paid").GetValueOrDefault()
```

or

```
Paid = row.Field<int?>("Paid") ?? 0
```

In both cases `Paid` will have a value of `0`, you can change if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own little function that does a simple check.

Along the lines of:
    public integer GetNumber (object val)
    {
           if (IsNumeric (val))
        {
           return val;
        } else
        {
           return 0;
         }
    }

I'm not fantastic with C#, but that should give you an idea. Sorry about formatting, I'm on a phone which doesn't help at all.